# Using the same container view to render and control multiple UIViews

Tags: swift, uiview, uicontainerview

I am still learning swift so please don't mind if my approach is wrong--

So i am trying to create a game and i have upto 4 players
I thought having a singular container view to render the views for them would be more efficient than to have to create separate views for each of them(but i cant figure out how to render them differently right now but intend to)

Is my approach to this wrong or should i keep going?

Comment: Can you share any code and screenshots showing what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure. here is the [idea of the setup](https://imgur.com/a/qDjGo?)  what i want to do is to make all four of the views show the same thing but still be able to manage each of their components(like the images buttons etc) via a controller

Comment: you can add four containerViews and constraint then as shown in your screenshot. After you've done that you will have four containerViews embedded with four different ViewControllers which you can access from mainViewController by using **mainViewController.childViewControllers**. make sense?

Comment: ok thanks ill try that!